# Laravel blade syntax for @if/@endif spacing issueif

Tags: laravel, syntax, laravel-blade

what is the similar blade syntax for the following code?

```
<?php if(...):?>abc<?php else:?>cde<?php endif;?>
```

the code 
@if(...) abc @else .... is no good as it ads a space before and after the "abc" the code @if(...)abc@endif (no spacing before and after html string) generates error ...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

The correct solution for this problem would be following:

```
@if(1==1){{ '1' }}@endif
```

---

This happens often and makes problem with "space sensitive" parts of code like values in `<option>` tags.

Having the `@if(1==1) 1 @endif` would be compiled to following which shows empty spaces around the number:

```
<?php if(1==1): ?> 1 <?php endif; ?>
```

Solution code would be compiled to this code:

```
<?php if(1==1): ?><?php echo e('1'); ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Which pretty much explains why this won't make additional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Did a bit more research and it looks like there is no solution as there is no spaceless tag in blade. I found a solution from someone who wrapping his string in extra hml tags (so that is easy as he ads spaces before and after the tag and the string inside tag si spaceless) but in my case I just need a string no spaces before and after ... I will go the old fashion php way ...

Comment: I think, a basic extra <span> tag should help you achieve what you looking for using blade directives till

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if(...) {{ 'abc' }} @else
```

Comment: i thought about that but it's UGLY ;) ... also tested this does not make any difference, the spaces are still added... abc == {{ 'abc' }} the problem is still the spaces before and after the {{ }}

Comment: UGLY!! You make me laugh.. :D :D

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems with spaces.
A workaround I use is this:
Put your if statement into php tags

```
@php
  $myVar = 'abc';
  if(...) $myVar = 'cde';
@endphp
```

and then echo the defined variable

```
{{$myVar}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but I still think we always should remember that it's a PHP environment...
So, simply:

```
@php
    if(...) echo "abc";
    else echo "cde";
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in case there is space issue between @if()@endif and @if.
I have replaced the @if() @endif with the {{$wardname}} variable to be printed using {{$wardname}}@if and its removed conflict with @endif & @if

and applied logic like:

```
if($city->wardname!="") {
    $wardname = "(".$city->wardname.")";
}else{
    $wardname = "";
}
```

Implemented it as:
{{$wardname}}@if

Answer (score -2):

The correct syntax is:

```
@if(...)
   abc
@else
   cde
@endif
```

I never saw unwanted spaces with this one.

Comment: yes there are spaces ... add something before the if and after the if (for example open and close brackets) and try to get the content inside near the brackets without space ... (@if(...) abc @endif ). I tis mandatory to have a space after the endif otherwise the word will not be understood by the parser. And that space is then applied to the result ... can you get a text like (abc) where the brackets are outside of the if statement and the abs is a result on the then or else branch ?